# Angular CLI - AOT error during ng build

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I created a application using Angular CLI and it works fine with the JIT compilation. I felt i need to make my application much faster so I planned to convert the application from JIT to AOT.

I followed the instructions which is being mentioned by angular.io

https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

This documentation.

I successfully converted steps which helps us to convert all files into ngFactory , did completed rollup process with no error.

I am getting error when i perform `ng build --aot`

The error message is as following

> Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically
>   analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins
>   options. Error: Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify
>   either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule
>   to the plugins options.
>       at Object.resolveEntryModuleFromMain (/Users/wakdev/WebstormProjects/wak_ang2_angcli/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/entry_resolver.js:128:11)
>       at AotPlugin._setupOptions (/Users/wakdev/WebstormProjects/wak_ang2_angcli/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:143:50)
>       at new AotPlugin (/Users/wakdev/WebstormProjects/wak_ang2_angcli/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:26:14)
>       at _createAotPlugin (/Users/wakdev/WebstormProjects/wak_ang2_angcli/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:55:12)
>       at Object.exports.getAotConfig (/Users/wakdev/WebstormProjects/wak_ang2_angcli/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:88:19)
>       at NgCliWebpackConfig.buildConfig (/Users/wakdev/WebstormProjects/wak_ang2_angcli/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-config.js:26:37)
>       at Class.run (/Users/wakdev/WebstormProjects/wak_ang2_angcli/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/build.js:27:92)
>       at Class.run (/Users/wakdev/WebstormProjects/wak_ang2_angcli/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/build.js:149:26)
>       at Class.Command.validateAndRun (/Users/wakdev/WebstormProjects/wak_ang2_angcli/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:128:15)
>       at /Users/wakdev/WebstormProjects/wak_ang2_angcli/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:92:22
>       at tryCatch (/Users/wakdev/WebstormProjects/wak_ang2_angcli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:539:12)
>       at invokeCallback (/Users/wakdev/WebstormProjects/wak_ang2_angcli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:554:13)
>       at /Users/wakdev/WebstormProjects/wak_ang2_angcli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:629:16
>       at flush (/Users/wakdev/WebstormProjects/wak_ang2_angcli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2414:5)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

here is my main.ts

```
import { platformBrowser }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppModuleNgFactory} from '../aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory';

console.log('Running AOT compiled');
//platformServer().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

my tsconfig-aot.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  },

  "files": [
    "src/app/app.module.ts",
    "src/main.ts",
  ],

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit" : true
  }
}
```

Does anyone has the same issue

Comment: If you are using angular-cli, follow it's own documentation. Your folder structure is not correct. Your main.ts should import the module that is in the same folder with it.

Comment: Those instructions are for manually implementing AOT for projects not using the Angular CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if you are using the cli, then running `ng build --prod` should do the building, aot and tree shaking for you. If you are wanting to do it the more manual route, as you are doing above you need to add another line to your `angularCompileOptions` so that they look like this:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "entryModule": "app/app.module#AppModule",
    "skipMetadataEmit" : true
  }
```

As you don't show your actual module, you might have to update the path and module name, but that property is most likely what you are missing.

Comment: ng build --prod command works fine without any issue,
but when i try to use the manual configuration 
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "genDir": "aot",
   "entryModule": "app/app.module#AppModule",
   "skipMetadataEmit" : true
 }
This one doesn't work

Comment: It really depends on your project. It is possible the path I posted is off or the naming. Looking at the rest of the file you posted, maybe it needs to be `"src/app/app.module#AppModule"`.